How do RNNs handle negation in sentiment analysis
I'm trying to understand how Recurrent Neural Networks (RNNs), such as LSTM or GRU models or just a simple RNN, handle negation in sentiment analysis. Specifically, I'm curious about how these models manage to correctly interpret sentences where negation changes the sentiment, such as "The movie is not good."
A simple model using word embeddings + simple averaging fails to handle negation properly. For example, if "good" has a positive sentiment score and "bad" has a negative sentiment score, a model might misinterpret "not good" by simply averaging the scores of "not" and "good".
Example Without Negation
Consider the following sentences with sentiment words:

"The movie is good."
"The movie is awesome."
"The movie is terrible."

Suppose we have the following word embeddings representing sentiment scores:

"good" = [10]
"awesome" = [12]
"terrible" = [-10]

Neutral words (assuming embeddings around 0):

"the" = [0]
"movie" = [0]
"is" = [0]

For these sentences, a simple global average of the sentiment scores works well:

"The movie is good" = average([0, 0, 0, 10]) = 10 / 4 = 2.5 (positive sentiment)
"The movie is awesome" = average([0, 0, 0, 12]) = 12 / 4 = 3 (positive sentiment)
"The movie is terrible" = average([0, 0, 0, -10]) = -10 / 4 = -2.5 (negative sentiment)

Example With Negation
Now, consider sentences with negation:

"The movie is not good."
"The movie is not bad."

For the embeddings:

"not" = [-5]
"good" = [10]
"bad" = [-9]

Simple averaging might fail to handle these correctly:

"The movie is not good" = average([0, 0, 0, -5, 10]) = (0 + 0 + 0 - 5 + 10) / 5 = 5 / 5 = 1 (incorrectly positive)
"The movie is not bad" = average([0, 0, 0, -5, -9]) = (0 + 0 + 0 - 5 - 9) / 5 = -14 / 5 = -2.8 (incorrectly negative)

How RNNs Handle Negation
Intuitively, an RNN should be able to handle this because it is designed to model sequences of words, capturing the dependencies between them over time.
Can someone explain, with a concrete example, how an RNN model like an LSTM or GRU can correctly understand and model negation in a sentence? Specifically, I'm interested in:

How the recurrent connections and memory cells capture the relationship between words like "not" and "good" or "not" and "bad".
An example with numerical values to illustrate the process.


RNNs consider the whole sequence of the words, and this is one big advantage over bag-of-words approaches.
The embeddings are the input to the RNN and the sentiment scores are the output; The RNN maps the embeddings to the sentiment. The embedding itself does not represent the sentiment.
To train the RNN, you will give it the overall sentiment of the whole phrase.

"The movie is good" = 10
"The movie is awesome" = 12
"The movie is terrible" = -10
"The movie is not good" = -5
"The movie is not bad" = 5

With enough examples, the network will be able to infer the sentiment of phrases is has never seen before, such as:

"The movie is not terrible" = ? (hopefully slightly positive!)

Inside the RNN is a memory, which is a (compressed) representation of the input history.
We can think of how the RNN might produce the output as we feed in an input sequence. Consider the possible output when the RNN has seen the sequence 'The movie is not...'.
So far, this has a more or less neutral sentiment. Perhaps the model will give it a very slightly negative score.
The RNN however has now seen the word 'not' and will remember that whatever comes next should be negated.
Thus, if it next sees a positive word ('The movie is not good') it will know to invert the sentiment, and score it negative overall.
Conversely, if it sees a negative word ('The movie is not bad') it will know to invert the sentiment, and score it positive overall.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
